# PHPExcel whitespaces not removed from individual cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an Excel file with values as follows.

```
 avi|boom|
ben |boom|
```

I upload the file and use phpExcel to read and get values from each cell.
The whitespaces before avi and after ben how do I remove them in php. 
I tried using the trim function but data is stored in database with whitespaces.

```
trim($sheet->getCell('B'.$row )->getValue());
```

data still gets stored with whitespaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The additional whitespace is a non-breaking whitespace character (xA0), not a standard value included in php trim(). You can remove it using the following trim modification.

```
trim(iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",$sheet->getCell('B'.$row )->getValue())," \t\n\r\0\x0B\xA0");
```

Comment: convert the encoding ISO so the characters can be detected. you can utf8_encode() the output afterward if necessary.

Comment: `trim(utf8_decode($sheet->getCell('B'.$row )->getValue())," \t\n\r\0\x0B\xA0");` should also work.

Comment: if you are working in utf8, remember to `utf8_encode()` the output